# Can "cuando" trigger the past subjuntive?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

I have often seen explanations of when ***cuando*** triggers the subjunctive to only apply to the future, basically in the "as soon as" sense and then not triggering it in the "generally happens" case nor when using the accented version nor in the past.

However, in print I have seen it seemingly be used to trigger a past subjuntive.

Some examples:

> Al igual que la fiscal Magallanes, el juez Vargas se comprometió a estudiar la denuncia y a pronunciarse **cuando tuviera** un criterio formado.

and

> Había viajado a Washington para participar en una reunión organizada por Hernando de Soto con el Instituto Demócrata de los Estados Unidos a la que asistiría la Secretaria de Estado Madelaine Albright, y aproveché para llevar a mi hija Camila, de 11 años en ese entonces, para ir con ella a Disney **cuando terminara** el evento.

These examples are from the book: Caiga Quien Caiga by José Ugaz

I have included the complete sentences for context in case there is another reason the subjunctive has been triggered unrelated to cuando.

Is the subjuntive being triggered by ***cuando***, something other than ***cuando*** or is this a grammatical error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In these cases, it is still future.  The problem I think you're having is thinking of the future as being *relative to now*, when there's also a future *relative to the past*.  So in the given time lines, the event in subjunctive hasn't yet occurred, which applies the same concept as using the subjunctive in the present/future-of-present.  If the verb in the *cuando* clause referred to habitual actions in the past, it would go in imperfect.

Comment: cuando tuviera is not future. cuando tuviera is past subjunctive. and cuando terminara is also.

Comment: @Lambie I didn't say it was future tense. It's an action that occurs in the future relative to the past anchor.

Comment: I can't understand your answer very well, to be frank. There is no future relative to past.

Comment: "Hay algo que va a suceder o que sucederá" hace referencia a algo en el futuro con respecto a ahora, por lo tanto, se usa el futuro del indicativo o el futuro perifrástico en el presente.  Podemos convertir la oración en forma pretérita, "Había algo que iba a suceder" y se refiere a algo que *ocurriría* en el futuro de algún momento pretérito, fuese antes o después de del presente.   Andrés Bello denominaba al condicional *pospretérito* por una razón.  Y donde se usa el presente del subjuntivo en cláusulas temporales, igual se emplea el imperfecto del subjuntivo.

Comment: Yes, ocurriría =que ***pudiera*** succeder. Pero no es un futuro. Andrés Bello lo dice bien: condicional postpretérito.

Comment: @Lambie ¿Cómo que no es un futuro? Acaso no te es válido decir, literalmente, «El hombre me dijo que **en el futuro** iría al extranjero cuando tuviese el dinero»? La idea de un futuro relativo a un pasado en vez de al presente no es nada extraña. Cuando hablamos de personas históricas, frecuentemente decimos «la futura presidenta» para alguien que llegaría a serlo.  Es futuro, aunque ya ocurrió porque se ancla en el pasado. Además, llamarlo *futuro del pasado* no es cosa mía, y así lo dicen muchos académicos y obras de lingüística —hasta la Nueva Gramática la usa para hablar del condicional—.

Comment: Volvamos al principio. Dijiste: "In these cases, it is still future."  No, there is no future. There is a possible action that comes after some other one. The events in the subjunctive are doubtful. It is not certain they will ever occur at all. The word future does not apply here.

Comment: @Lambie y otra vez es un futuro, y que al final ocurrió o no no impide llamarlo así. Decir «cuando vuelvas, te lo daré» la acción expresada en *vuelvas* es futuro aunque se conjugue en presente (antiguamente usaba el futuro  del subjuntivo) y no tenemos ninguna constancia de que en cualquier momento vayas a volver. Como obviamente no usas la palabra futuro de la misma forma que el resto del mundo, es mejor que dejemos de discutir.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can when the circumstance,  as @guifa stated, being referred to "is a future relative to the past."

> Al igual que la fiscal Magallanes, el juez Vargas se comprometió a estudiar la denuncia y a pronunciarse cuando **tuviera** un criterio formado.

Could also be:

> Al igual que la fiscal Magallanes, el juez Vargas se comprometió a estudiar la denuncia y a pronunciarse cuando **tuvo** un criterio formado.

But the implication is different.  The first statement is implying that there was a feeling of being unsure when he would complete the task.  The latter is just telling a story in the past with no implication as to a special narrative occurring in relation to the completion of his task.

Answer (score 0):

> Both sentences you posted as narrated **in the past tense**. There
>   could not possibly, therefore, be a future tense in them.
>
> cuando triggers the present subjunctive when you are speaking in the
>   present: 
>
> Me voy/marcharé
>
>  cuando **vuelvas**.

1) So: Al igual que la fiscal Magallanes, el juez Vargas **se comprometió** a estudiar la denuncia y a pronunciarse cuando tuviera un criterio formado.

- Therefore, it could not be in the future.

An easier example: **Me dijo** tu hermano que cuando **tuvieras terminado** el trabajo, volverias.

BUT: **Me dice** tu hermano que **cuando tengas terminado** el trabajo, volverás.

Your brother **told me** that when he **had finished the job**, he would return.

2) [...] **aproveché** para llevar a mi hija Camila, de 11 años en ese entonces, para ir con ella a Disney **cuando terminara** el evento.

terminara is past subjunctive, not future [no accent on the a]

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine that a contemporary narrator describes the same Vargas story, with the main verb in the present tense:

> El juez Vargas se está comprometiendo a pronunciarse cuando tenga un criterio formado.

If we now want to shift the main verb to the past, we have two choices for the "cuando" clause:

> (a) El juez Vargas se comprometió a pronunciarse cuando tenga un criterio formado.
>
> (b) El juez Vargas se comprometió a pronunciarse cuando tuviera un criterio formado.

We would use (a) right after a press conference; we would use (b) when describing events in a somewhat more distant past.

In the Disney example, only "terminara" would work, so I won't bother going through the shift and then shift back exercise.  But I do recommend using this shifting technique to understand complex sentences with past tenses better.